# How to concatenate element-wise two lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and I want to concatenate them element-wise. One of the list is subjected to string-formatting before concatenation.

For example :

```
a = [0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 11] 
b = ['asp1', 'asp1', 'asp1', 'asp1', 'asp2', 'asp2']
```

In this case, `a` is subjected to string-formatting. That is, new `a` or `aa` should be :

```
aa = [00, 01, 05, 06, 10, 11]
```

Final output should be :

```
c = ['asp100', 'asp101', 'asp105', 'asp106', 'asp210', 'asp211']
```

Can somebody please tell me how to do that?

Comment: try to play with [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`string.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano Thanks, answer by nightcracker is working fine!

Comment: @nightcracker Thanks for the answer. Yes, sure. But, I can not accept your answer just now. It is showing to wait for 5 mins. Then, I will do that :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use [**`zip`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> ["{}{:02}".format(b_, a_) for a_, b_ in zip(a, b)]
['asp100', 'asp101', 'asp105', 'asp106', 'asp210', 'asp211']
```

Comment: @dmedvinsky What about this? `c = map("{0[1]}{0[0]:02}".format, zip(a, b))` Let the magic commence!

Comment: @nightcracker: good. The example with `map` works in python2. For python3 you need `list(map(...))` if you want a list, while the list comprehension works for both

Comment: You don't *need* that, you just need it if you need to have a list (i.e. a iterable is not sufficient).

Answer (score 41):

Using zip

```
[m+str(n) for m,n in zip(b,a)]
```

output

```
['asp10', 'asp11', 'asp15', 'asp16', 'asp210', 'asp211']
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match the OP's request. 'asp10' != 'asp100'

Answer (score 9):

Other solution (preferring *printf formating* style over `.format()` usage), it's also smaller:

```
>>> ["%s%02d" % t for t in zip(b, a)]
['asp100', 'asp101', 'asp105', 'asp106', 'asp210', 'asp211']
```

Answer (score 5):

Than can be done elegantly with map and zip:

```
map(lambda (x,y): x+y, zip(list1, list2))
```

Example:

```
In [1]: map(lambda (x,y): x+y, zip([1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]))
Out[1]: [5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Comment: it doesn't do what the OP asks

Comment: No, but it is the general pattern, I think that is more important.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks, I'm getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` with this example of code....

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to concatenate arbitrary number of lists, you could do this:

```
In [1]: lists = [["a", "b", "c"], ["m", "n", "o"], ["p", "q", "r"]] # Or more

In [2]: lists
Out[2]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['m', 'n', 'o'], ['p', 'q', 'r']]    

In [4]: list(map("".join, zip(*lists)))
Out[4]: ['amp', 'bnq', 'cor']
```

Comment: I think, this answer should get more credit. If one has variable number of lists. Let's say in data preparation you have positives and negatives (user can define the number of negatives), then the above solution will solve this issue with variable number of negatives list.

Answer (score 3):

inputs:

```
a = [0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 11] 
b = ['asp1', 'asp1', 'asp1', 'asp1', 'asp2', 'asp2']

concat_func = lambda x,y: x + "" + str(y)

list(map(concat_func,b,a)) # list the map function
```

output:

```
['asp10', 'asp11', 'asp15', 'asp16', 'asp210', 'asp211']
```

Comment: can this be done for lists with different length?

Answer (score 2):

not using zip.  I dunno, I think this is the obvious way to do it.  Maybe I just learnt C first :)

```
c=[]
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    c.append("%s%02d" % (b[i],a[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b = ['asp1', 'asp1', 'asp1', 'asp1', 'asp2', 'asp2']
aa = [0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 11]
new_list =[]
if len(aa) != len(b):
     print 'list length mismatch'
else:
    for each in range(0,len(aa)):
        new_list.append(b[each] + str(aa[each]))
print new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a temporary DataFrame, it's readable and fast:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["1", "2", "3"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": b})
df["c"] = df.a + df.b
result = df.c.values
```

Output:

```
$ result 
["a1", "b2", "c3"]
```

Behind the scenes, DataFrames use numpy, so the result is efficient.

---

And the same thing as a function:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import List
def _elementwise_concat(self, a: List[str], b: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    """
    Elementwise concatenate.
    :param a: List of strings.
    :param b: List of strings.
    :return: List, same length, strings concatenated.
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": b})
    df["c"] = df.a + df.b
    return df.c.values
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension / `zip()` / use of `zfill()` to format.

```
print ([y+str(x).zfill(2) for x,y in zip(a,b)])
```

Output:

```
['asp100', 'asp101', 'asp105', 'asp106', 'asp210', 'asp211']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lambda` and `format`:

```
b = ['asp1', 'asp1', 'asp1', 'asp1', 'asp2', 'asp2']
a = [0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 11]

list(map(lambda x: x[0] + "{0:0=2d}".format(x[1]), zip(b, a)))
```

Out:

```
['asp100', 'asp101', 'asp105', 'asp106', 'asp210', 'asp211']
```