# How do I get my nested loop function to iterate through the entire (at least 2) list variables and append to a new list output?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm trying to write a function that takes 2 list variables i.e. `first_names` and `last_names`.

I'm using a nested for loop in my function to iterate through both lists and append the values to return a new 'combined' variable list.

The function takes the two list parameters but iterates through just the first index value [0] of each list and outputs that - the loop ends.

```
first_names = ["Dave", "James", "Steve"]

last_names = ["Smith", "Jones", "Jackson"]

def NameCombine(first_names,last_names):
    combined = []
        for first in first_names:
            for last in last_names:
                combined.append(first+last)
                return combined

print(NameCombine(first_names,last_names))
```

Expected output: `DaveSmith, JamesJones, SteveJackson`

Actual output: `DaveSmith`

I'm expecting a new combined list of both the first and last name at each index.

But it's returning the first two values of each list and then the loop ends.

Comment: Think about where you are returning from the function. How many elements have you iterated over at that point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate element-wise two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560044/how-to-concatenate-element-wise-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: Apologies all - left the while condition in the when i was experimenting and forgot to delete before copying over. Edited and corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them with `zip` within comprehension:

```
def NameCombine(first_names,last_names):
    return [a+b for a, b in zip(first_names, last_names)]
```

Comment: This achieves the target output and props to @Pasan Chamikara for his answer which includes formatting too.

I'm still trying to figure out if my original code can achieve the same output using a nested loop.

Comment: You got the logic right but the indentation was missing. Although the answer from @Pasan will work, but what this solution is more elegant and pythonic way to achieve the same result in a single line of code

Answer (score 1):

Since most of them here answer specifically to your question. I would like to add the other way of achieving the solution to this problem as below,

here I used `map` and `add` from operator module

```py
list(map(operator.add, first_names, last_names))
# ['DaveSmith', 'JamesJones', 'SteveJackson']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this code.

```
first_names = ["Dave", "James", "Steve"]

last_names = ["Smith", "Jones", "Jackson"]

def NameCombine(first_names, last_names):
    combined = []
    for i in range(0, len(first_names)):
        if last_names[i] != None:
            combined.append(first_names[i] + " " + last_names[i])
        else:
            combined.append(first_names[i])
    return combined

print(NameCombine(first_names,last_names))
```

Comment: Thanks @Pasan Chamikara. While this does achieve my target output, I'm still trying to figure out how to achieve the same output using a nested loop.

Comment: @DJoseph1 - A loop cycling three times nested in a loop also cycling three times yields a total of nine cycles, i. e. nine resulting values, while you only want three resulting values. Therefore, a nested loop cannot achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic and list comprehension is my preferred way. But if you really wanted a solution using a nested loop, this would work for you. Just used your code and added an additional condition to only print the desired result.

The results from this solution are: ['DaveSmith', 'JamesJones', 'SteveJackson']

```
first_names = ["Dave", "James", "Steve"]

last_names = ["Smith", "Jones", "Jackson"]

def NameCombine(first_names,last_names):
  combined = []
  for first in first_names:
    for last in last_names:
      if first_names.index(first) == last_names.index(last):
        combined.append(first+last)
  return combined

print(NameCombine(first_names,last_names))
```