# Python interlacing two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```py
names = ['some_name', 'other_name']
status = ['queued', 'in-progress']
```

how can I join them to look like this:

```py
list = ['some_name queued', 'other_name in-progress']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate element-wise two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560044/how-to-concatenate-element-wise-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
names = ['some_name', 'other_name'] 
status = ['queued', 'in-progress']

result = ['{} {}'.format(name, status) for name, status in zip(names, status)]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['some_name queued', 'other_name in-progress']
```