# Why are my the delimiters not random enough and the numbers subdomain count range aren't correct?

Tags: python, random, jupyter-notebook

Hello guys i want to ask, why are my punctuations on my domain name generator not random enough? here is my code

```
import random

Example = open("dictionaries/examples.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8")
with open("dictionaries/Combined.txt") as i:
    Test = [line.rstrip() for line in i]
```

This is a few words what inside the combined text file

```
 Example ['login', 'confirm', 'signup', 'confirmation', 'enroll', 'mobile', 'access',
'claim', 'service', 'group', 'recovery', 'support', 'find', 'confirmation']

delimeters = ['', '-', '.']
web = 'web'
subdomain_count2 = 2
subdomain_count3 = 3
subdomain_count4 = 4
suffix = ['co.id', 'info', 'id', 'com']
output = []
for i in range(100):
    outputs = []
    for j in range(subdomain_count2):
        outputs.append(random.choice(Test))
    data = outputs + [web]
    random.shuffle(data)
    for k in range(subdomain_count3):
        outputs.append(random.choice(Test))
    data2 = outputs + [web]
    random.shuffle(data2)
    for l in range(subdomain_count4):
        outputs.append(random.choice(Test))
    data3 = outputs + [web]
    random.shuffle(data3)
    prefix = random.choice(delimeters).join(data)
    prefix2 = random.choice(delimeters).join(data2)
    prefix3 = random.choice(delimeters).join(data3)
    out = random.choice(delimeters).join([prefix])
    out2 = random.choice(delimeters).join([prefix2])
    out3 = random.choice(delimeters).join([prefix3])
    tld = random.choice(suffix)
    addr1 = '.'.join([out, tld])
    addr2 = '.'.join([out2, tld])
    addr3 = '.'.join([out3, tld])
    addr = (addr1 + '\n' + addr2 + '\n' + addr3 + '\n')
    output.append(addr)
    Example.write(addr)

with open("dictionaries/examples.txt") as f:
    websamples = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

This is the output that i get.

[image: Output]

As you can see from the image that the domain punctuation is pretty straightforward and has no variation for the domain name. it should've looked like this `web-loginconfirm.co.id` or `web.login-confirm.co.id` since I have made the `delimiters = ['', '-',` .`]` so there would be a combination where there are 3 characters connected with the punctuation like this `web-confirm.group.com` or `confirm.web-group.com` and there are also 3 characters that connects without the punction like this `webclaimservice.com`.

And also as you can see on the 2nd domain and 3rd domain, it somehow does not follow the subdomain number that I want based on this code line for example if `subdomain_count3 = 3` there should've only been 3 subdomains. On the 2nd domain (excluding the web variable since it's a fixed one and I want it to always show up on every domain) `signup-login-web-confirmation-confirm-enroll.co.id`, there are 5 subdomains instead of 3 subdomains `(signup, login, confirmation, confirm, enroll)`. Is there a reason why the delimiters are not random enough and also the subdomain count on the 2nd and the 3rd one has too many variables than i wanted?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Okay for the subdomain range one I have actually found the solution.

I basically added another output name for each subdomain

```
for i in range(5):
    outputs = []
    outputs2 = []
    outputs3 = []
```

[image: Correct Output]

No need to answer the 2nd question, i still need help of the first one

thanks!

Comment: You are asking many questions here, so its not clear what you want, but firstly I think that you use: `outputs.append(...)` without using `outputs=[]` before the loop, so you retain the previous contents. Secondly you have: `random.choice(delimeters).join(data)` which randomly picks just one of the delimiters and uses that alone to join the parts in `data`.

Comment: For the 2nd question there's no need to answer it, I have found the solution. but is still need help on the first one @quamrana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain punctuation varies between the three domains generated in the main loop, for example the three domain names with `find` in them one has a dot and the other has nothing. You are only choosing the delimiter once, and using that one delimiter to join all the elements in `data`:

```
prefix = random.choice(delimeters).join(data)
```

You are adding to the same output list for the second and third subdomains, either don't do that (in which case you can get rid of 2/3 of the code and just  loop over three different values for the number of domains to add) or only add the difference between `subdomain_count3` and `subdomain_count2` subdomains.

You can also use `random.choices` to get a list of `k` choices rather than looping and calling `random.choice` repeatedly. Do that twice - once for the domain parts and once for the delimiters, then zip the lists.

```
import random
Test = ['login', 'confirm', 'signup', 'confirmation', 'enroll', 'mobile', 'access',
        'claim', 'service', 'group', 'recovery', 'support', 'find', 'confirmation']

delimiters = ['', '-', '.']
web = 'web'
suffix = ['co.id', 'info', 'id', 'com']
output = []

for i in range(100):
    for subdomain_count in [2, 3, 4]:
        data = [web] + random.choices(Test, k=subdomain_count)
        random.shuffle(data)
        delims = (random.choices(delimiters, k=subdomain_count) +
            ['.' + random.choice(suffix)])
        address = ''.join([a+b for a, b in zip(data, delims)])
        output.append(address)

for o in output:
    print(o)
```

Comment: Oh wow, this one is much shorter and much simpler than the code that I made, i want to ask with this code line `address = ''.join([a+b for a, b in zip(data, delims)])` can you explain on how this one works? do the a and b represent data and delims? @Pete_Kirkham

Comment: I also want to ask again, if i want to add `{'http://', 'https://']` in front of the subdomains what should i do? i tried putting it in this line `address = ''.join([a+b+c for a, b, c in zip(http, data, delims)])` it only outputs the h word and no the the whole word

Comment: @Tsukuru Yes, `a` and `b` unpack the zipped data and delims elements.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560044/how-to-concatenate-element-wise-two-lists-in-python .

To add a protocol, the easiest way is to just prepend it to the string at the end in the `address = ...` line; adding another parameter to zip will treat that as a sequence to be zipped not an extra element in the sequences.